# Ordering relations : alternatives to the somewhat confusing terminology " a precedes b and conversely b dominates a"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

If R is an ordering relation, the fact  that a*R*b ( or that (a,b) belongs to R) is often expressed as (1) a precedes b and conversely (2) b dominates a. ( Example, Lipschutz, Theory and Problems of Set Theory, Ch.10).

But this terminology is a little confusing or at least infelicitous since to " dominate" is litteraly to come first in terms of strength or power. In antiquity, the dominus had a higher rank  in social hierarchy than had his slave. So " dominates" seems to say the contrary of what it is meant to express.

Are there known alternatives to the " precedes/dominates" terminology?

What would be a better term that "dominating" for the converse of " preceeding" ?

Comment: You could use $b$ majorizes $a$, or simply $b$ is larger than $a$, (or larger or  equal, depending on the relation,) and $a$ is smaller then $b$

Comment: Yes.  The usual are less than and greater than.

Comment: following ? To follow, to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [successor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function) is an example for functions. But it really depends on what you are ordering, it could be by inclusion of subsets, meaning b includes a. It could be by something else, dominates is just a general term. Not everything in life means it's greek roots, not all autism is a believe or practice pertaining to ones self. Sometimes there's just not a better term.